# How can I add a custom button to the post editor?

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor, dashboard, editor

I want to have a custom button in my post editor, but everything I find online is for the previous, classic editor of WordPress and none of them seem to work with the new Gutenberg thing.

Red mark is where I want it to be. Either on top, alongside "Publish" and others, or inside a metabox:
[image]

I tried:

```php
add_action( 'edit_form_top', 'custom_button');
add_action( 'media_buttons_context', 'custom_button' );
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'custom_button' );
add_action( 'post_submitbox_minor_actions', 'custom_button' );
add_action( 'post_submitbox_start', 'custom_button' );
```

where `custom_button` just `echo`s a simple HTML element (button or link):

```php
function custom_button(){
    $html  = '<a>Do Something</a>';
    echo $html;
}
```

What is wrong here? Is it something not supported in Gutenberg? Or do I need to set priorities on the `add_action` (I want to add this button from a plugin, not `functions.php`).
Are there any alternatives to this?

Comment: None of those hooks are supported in the block editor. The block editor functions completely differently to the classic editor, and most (if not all) classic editor related hooks will not work in the block editor.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. What's the alternative then?

Comment: I'll need to double check if it's even possible in this specific spot, but it's late in my timezone so I'll come back to this later if somebody doesn't provide an answer sooner.

Comment: Like in your successor question, don't use PHP. What you want instead is https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/slotfills/plugin-document-setting-panel/. Classic editor was built with PHP - javascript - jQuery, however, block-editor is built with javascript - React - Redux (and using PHP only for REST responses)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this "the right way"? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @joho Nope.....

Comment: @Shahriar Not sure if this is any help to you: https://neliosoftware.com/blog/how-to-add-button-gutenberg-blocks/